# Pre-Train a Model using imitation learning with Stable-baselines3

Tags: python, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have been trying to figure out a way to Pre-Train a model using Stable-baselines3.

In the original documentation for Stable-baseline (the version which runs on Tensorflow 1.X), this seems to be an easy task:

```py
    from stable_baselines import PPO2
    
    from stable_baselines.gail import ExpertDataset
    
    dataset = ExpertDataset(expert_path='expert_cartpole.npz', traj_limitation=1, batch_size=128)
    
    model = PPO2('MlpPolicy', 'CartPole-v1', verbose=1)
    
    \# Pretrain the PPO2 model
    
    model.pretrain(dataset, n_epochs=1000)
```

The problem is, there is no "from stable_baselines***3***.gail import ExpertDataset"

basically what I want to do is I want to create a .npz file using a specific algorithm to generate the observation, rewards, action and then pass that to an RL agent.

I found the original code from this document:

https://readthedocs.org/projects/stable-baselines/downloads/pdf/master/

update 4 March 2023:
I found this link that explains how this was done on Stable Baseline:
https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/pretrain.html
And I want to do the exact same thing on SB3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`imitation`](https://github.com/HumanCompatibleAI/imitation), which is built on top of SB3.

```bash
pip install imitation
```

Then you can use:

```py
from imitation.algorithms.adversarial.gail import GAIL
```

Here is [their docs](https://imitation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/algorithms/gail.html)

Comment: Thanks Minh-Long, I have seen that API but the issue is still the same. the imitation API does not provide `ExpertDataset(expert_path='expert_cartpole.npz', traj_limitation=1, batch_size=128)` With the imitation API, I'd need to save my expert data myself and then load it as numpy arrays and then pass it to `train_disc(*, expert_samples=None, gen_samples=None)`